# I need to migrate On-prem and AWS environments to Azure Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, architecture, migration

please advise if my plan order and tooling stack is good:

Not sure best practice to migrate Kuberenetes without down time?!?!

Existing Infrastructure:

• Fortinet Firewall – In AWS and in On-Premise.

- MySql on RDS
  • Two Kubernetes Clusters EKS AND Kubernetes On-Premise
  • For logging in an on-premises environment, they are using ElasticSearch.
  • Spark & Hadoop – ML in On-Premises

I need it to be cost optimized and Low latency

1.Database :
Use Azure Database Migration Service to migrate SQL databases from RDS to Azure SQL
2.Monitoring:
Migrate from ElasticSearch to Azure Monitor and Azure Log Analytics for integrated logging and monitoring. Consider using Azure Data Explorer for high-volume log analytics.
Utilize Azure Sentinel for security information and event management (SIEM) to enhance security posture.
3. Firewall Migration:

Replace Fortinet Firewalls with Azure Firewall, a managed cloud-based network security service. Additionally, use Azure Network Security Groups (NSGs) for micro-segmentation.
Consider implementing Azure Firewall Manager to centrally manage multiple Azure Firewall instances.

Spark & Hadoop Migration:
Migrate ML workloads to Azure Databricks for Spark-based analytics and AI. Azure Databricks provides a fast, easy, and collaborative Apache Spark-based analytics platform.
For Hadoop workloads, consider Azure HDInsight, a cloud service that makes it easy, fast, and cost-effective to process massive amounts of data.

Network Optimization: Use Azure ExpressRoute for private connections between Azure datacenters and infrastructure on-premises or in other clouds to reduce latency.
Scalability and High Availability:
Consider the use of Azure Front Door or Azure Traffic Manager for global load balancing and ensuring low latency across geographic locations.